# Priority based categorization using pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I've invoice related data in the below Dataframe and lists of codes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'invoice':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7],
    'code':[101,104,105,101,106,106,104,101,104,105,111,109,111,110,101,114,112],
    'qty':[2,1,1,3,2,4,7,1,1,1,1,4,2,1,2,2,1]
})

+---------+------+-----+
| invoice | code | qty |
+---------+------+-----+
|    1    |  101 |  2  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    1    |  104 |  1  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    2    |  105 |  1  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    2    |  101 |  3  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    2    |  106 |  2  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    3    |  106 |  4  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    3    |  104 |  7  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    3    |  101 |  1  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    4    |  104 |  1  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    4    |  105 |  1  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    4    |  111 |  1  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    5    |  109 |  4  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    5    |  111 |  2  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    6    |  110 |  1  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    6    |  101 |  2  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    6    |  114 |  2  |
+---------+------+-----+
|    7    |  104 |  2  |
+---------+------+-----+
```

code lists are,

```
Soda =  [101,102]
Hot =  [103,109]
Juice =  [104,105]
Milk =  [106,107,108]
Dessert =  [110,111]
```

My task is to add a new `category` column based on the below specified `Order of Priority`.

1. Priority No.1 : if any invoice has more than 10 qty should be categorized as `Mega`. eg : sum of `qty` of `invoice 3 is 12`
2. Priority No.2 : from the `rest of the invoice`. if any `code` of the `invoice` is in the `Milk` list, then the category should be `Healthy`. eg : in `invoice 2` `code 106` is in `Milk`. hence, the Full invoice is categorized as `Healthy`. Irrespective of other items (`code 101 & 105`) are present in the invoice. As priorities are applied to the `full` invoice.
3. Priority No.3 : from the `rest of the invoice`, if any `code` of the `invoice` is in `Juice` list, then this has `2 parts`

(3.1) if the sum of that juices qty is `equal to 1`, then category should be `OneJuice`. eg : `invoice 1` has `code 104` and `qty 1`.this `invoice 1` will get `OneJuice` irrespective of other items (`code 101`) are present in the invoice. As priorities are applied to the `full` invoice.

(3.2) if the sum of that juices qty is `greater than 1`, category should be `ManyJuice`. eg : `invoice 4` has `code 104 & 105`  and `qty 1 + 1 = 2`.

4. Priority No.4 : from the `rest of the invoice`, if any `code` of the invoice is in `Hot` list, then it should be categorized as `HotLovers`. Irrespective of other items are present in the invoice.
5. Priority No.5 : from the `rest of the invoice`, if any `code` of the invoice is in `Dessert` list, then it should be categorized as `DessertLovers`.
6. Finally, rest of all the invoice should be categorized as `Others`.

My desired output is as below.

```
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
| invoice | code | qty |    category   |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    1    |  101 |  2  |    OneJuice   |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    1    |  104 |  1  |    OneJuice   |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    2    |  105 |  1  |    Healthy    |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    2    |  101 |  3  |    Healthy    |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    2    |  106 |  2  |    Healthy    |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    3    |  106 |  4  |      Mega     |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    3    |  104 |  7  |      Mega     |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    3    |  101 |  1  |      Mega     |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    4    |  104 |  1  |   ManyJuice   |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    4    |  105 |  1  |   ManyJuice   |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    4    |  111 |  1  |   ManyJuice   |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    5    |  109 |  4  |   HotLovers   |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    5    |  111 |  2  |   HotLovers   |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    6    |  110 |  1  | DessertLovers |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    6    |  101 |  2  | DessertLovers |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    6    |  114 |  2  | DessertLovers |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
|    7    |  104 |  2  |     ManyJuice |
+---------+------+-----+---------------+
```

so far I have tried below. it works. but pretty naive and not pythonic at all. also when i applied this to the original datatset, the code is very very slow.

```
# Calculating Priority No.1 
L = df.groupby(['invoice'])['qty'].transform('sum') >= 10
df_Large = df[L]['invoice'].to_frame()
df_Large['category'] = 'Mega'
df_Large.drop_duplicates(['invoice'], inplace=True)


# Calculating Priority No.2
df_1 = df[~L] # removing Priority No.1 calculated above
M = (df_1['code'].isin(Milk)
.groupby(df_1['invoice'])
.transform('any'))
df_Milk = df_1[M]['invoice'].to_frame()
df_Milk['category'] = 'Healthy'
df_Milk.drop_duplicates(['invoice'], inplace=True)

# Calculating Priority No.3

# 3.a Part -1

df_2 = df[~L & ~M]  # removing Priority No.1 & 2 calculated above
J_1 = (df_2['code'].isin(Juice)
.groupby(df_2['invoice'])
.transform('sum') == 1)
df_SM = df_2[J_1]['invoice'].to_frame()
df_SM['category'] = 'OneJuice'
df_SM.drop_duplicates(['invoice'], inplace=True)


# 3.b Part -2
J_2 = (df_2['code'].isin(Juice)
.groupby(df_2['invoice'])
.transform('sum') > 1)
df_MM = df_2[J_2]['invoice'].to_frame()
df_MM['category'] = 'ManyJuice'
df_MM.drop_duplicates(['invoice'], inplace=True)


# Calculating Priority No.4
df_3 = df[~L & ~M & ~J_1 & ~J_2]  # removing Priority No.1, 2 & 3 (a & b) calculated above
H = (df_3['code'].isin(Hot)
.groupby(df_3['invoice'])
.transform('any'))
df_Hot = df_3[H]['invoice'].to_frame()
df_Hot['category'] = 'HotLovers'
df_Hot.drop_duplicates(['invoice'], inplace=True)


# Calculating Priority No.5
df_4 = df[~L & ~M & ~J_1 & ~J_2 & ~H ] # removing Priority No.1, 2, 3 (a & b) and 4 calculated above
D = (df_4['code'].isin(Dessert)
.groupby(df_4['invoice'])
.transform('any'))
df_Dessert = df_4[D]['invoice'].to_frame()
df_Dessert['category'] = 'DessertLovers'
df_Dessert.drop_duplicates(['invoice'], inplace=True)

# merge all dfs
category = pd.concat([df_Large,df_Milk,df_SM,df_MM,df_Hot,df_Dessert], axis=0,sort=False, ignore_index=True)

# Final merge to the original dataset
df = df.merge(category,on='invoice', how='left').fillna(value='Others')
```

So need help to cleanup this code for speed/efficiency and pythonic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
df['category'] = np.select([
    df.groupby('invoice')['qty'].transform('sum') >= 10,
    df['code'].isin(Milk).groupby(df.invoice).transform('any'),
    (df['qty']*df['code'].isin(Juice)).groupby(df.invoice).transform('sum') == 1,
    (df['qty']*df['code'].isin(Juice)).groupby(df.invoice).transform('sum') > 1,
    df['code'].isin(Hot).groupby(df.invoice).transform('any'),
    df['code'].isin(Dessert).groupby(df.invoice).transform('any')
],
    ['Mega','Healthy','OneJuice','ManyJuice','HotLovers','DessertLovers'],
    'Other'
)
print(df)
```

Output

```
    invoice  code  qty       category
0         1   101    2       OneJuice
1         1   104    1       OneJuice
2         2   105    1        Healthy
3         2   101    3        Healthy
4         2   106    2        Healthy
5         3   106    4           Mega
6         3   104    7           Mega
7         3   101    1           Mega
8         4   104    1      ManyJuice
9         4   105    1      ManyJuice
10        4   111    1      ManyJuice
11        5   109    4      HotLovers
12        5   111    2      HotLovers
13        6   110    1  DessertLovers
14        6   101    2  DessertLovers
15        6   114    2  DessertLovers
16        7   104    2      ManyJuice
```

---

### Micro-Benchmark

```
pd.show_versions()

commit           : None
python           : 3.7.5.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Linux
OS-release       : 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
machine          : x86_64
processor        : x86_64
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : C.UTF-8
LOCALE           : en_US.UTF-8

pandas           : 0.25.3
numpy            : 1.17.4
```

Data was created with

```
def make_data(n):
     return pd.DataFrame({
    'invoice':np.arange(n)//3,
    'code':np.random.choice(np.arange(101,112),n),
    'qty':np.random.choice(np.arange(1,8), n, p=[10/25,10/25,1/25,1/25,1/25,1/25,1/25])
})
```

Results

```
perfplot.show(
    setup=make_data,
    kernels=[get_category, get_with_np_select],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(8, 20)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

[image: benchmark results]

Comment: Thank you. your code is very simple and easy to understand. however, when it comes to performance/speed, this is very very slow. After applying to my original datatset which is `11Mn rows and 10 columns` ,   after 30 minutes I forced stopped the code. as it is taking too long. even my code above took less time than that.

Comment: You're right! I didn't expected that. For 10000 rows np.select runs 7 sec on my machine, your code was 62 ms. I have to look into that.

Comment: I still don't know why the conditions in the previous version were evaluated so slow. If I find an explanation I'll add it for completeness.

Comment: Thank you. your code is superfast as per my expectation. however, your code is not giving the right answer in the below scenario. if an invoice has one line and it is a Juice code, the qty of which is `greater than 1` should be ManyJuice , according to your code it is calculates to `OneJuice`. try changing the last row of the dataframe in my example from `invoice 7, code 112, qty 1` to `invoice 7, code 104, qty 2`.

Comment: it's 'OneJuice' in your algorithm, too. But it's clearly not the desired output. Hmm ... If I find the time, I will look into it.

Comment: I mean after you change from `invoice 7, code 112, qty 1` to `invoice 7, code 104, qty 2` it should be `ManyJuice`. coz' the `qty is 2`.  this is an additional scenario I used it to evaluate the logic is correctly calculated by the code. please really appreciate if you could give me a solution.Thanks

Comment: Was missing some brackets. Now it's the correct output for the updated dataframe.

Comment: Thank you.  now the code takes around 48seconds to run in my original dataset

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny for knowledge purposes, `groupby(df['invoice'])` & `df['code']` are repeating almost every single line. how can we eliminate this duplication and write once ??  to avoid DRY- Don't Repeat Yourself.